# Change the base url of a durable function response while running behind a proxy

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-durable-functions

I am currently trying to setup a durable function behind a proxy (In his case, an Azure APIM instance).

The problem is though, that the response is a direct link to the function, but I want the link to point to the Apim instance. For example:

The Apim has the following url:

`https://apim.com`

and the azure function has the following url:

`https://function.com`

In order to start the durable function, I call

`https://apim.com/api/start`

But the body of the response looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": "[id]",
    "statusQueryGetUri": "https://function.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]?taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]",
    "sendEventPostUri": "https://function.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]/raiseEvent/{eventName}?taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]",
    "terminatePostUri": "https://function.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]/terminate?reason={text}&taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]",
    "purgeHistoryDeleteUri": "https://function.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]?taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]",
    "restartPostUri": "https://function.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]/restart?taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]"
}
```

Is there anyway to configure the service to use a different base url? This is the response I would like:

```json
{
    "id": "[id]",
    "statusQueryGetUri": "https://apim.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]?taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]",
    "sendEventPostUri": "https://apim.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]/raiseEvent/{eventName}?taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]",
    "terminatePostUri": "https://apim.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]/terminate?reason={text}&taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]",
    "purgeHistoryDeleteUri": "https://apim.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]?taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]",
    "restartPostUri": "https://apim.com/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/[instanceid]/restart?taskHub=[hub]&connection=Storage&code=[code]"
}
```

I tried changing the WEBSITE_HOSTNAME in the configuration, but I get the following error:

```
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: WEBSITE_HOSTNAME
```

I would really like to not have to manipulate the response body, but I am almost sure that changing the base url is supported.

The HTTP api documentation mentions that it is possible to assign custom domains to the function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#http-api-url-discovery), but all it does is mention that it is possible.

Comment: Could you please try to delete the configuration save it and make refresh and add again ..!

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - the configuration 'WEBSITE_HOSTNAME' never existed. Previously, I was trying to make it work on my dev machine. I decided that didn't make that much sense. I now tried changing it in the portal, but this time I get 
```Failed to update web app settings: THe data is not valid (Invalid or not allowed environment key name: WEBSITE_HOSTNAME).```

Comment: Could you please refer this suggestion once as mentioned in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3793#issuecomment-439876067)

Comment: But I am not trying to proxy a request in the app? The app is returning an invalid link, since the app is not available - it is only available through the apim. I want to configure the base url for those links so that they are not invalid.

Comment: Did you got to solve this?

Comment: BTW, what I believe they are mentioning is setting up a custom domain as explained in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain#azure-function-app)

Comment: I did solve it, but it was through string manipulation. Not the most elegant solution unfortunately. I'll have a look at the link you sent me - but we aren't using azure dns, so I don't know if it will work.